# SharePoint 2013 theme broken accidently

Tags: 2013, page-layout, design, design-manager

In SharePoint 2013 if I try to change the look, and select "Tokyo" from the Site Layouts dropdown, the elements in the preview are all broken.

Menu items are appearing on the page which should only appear on hover, ribbon is broken, names like "BrowseTab 1 of 3, PageTab 2 of 3 SiteTab 3 of 3" are appearing.

I have not deleted any css or js or aspx file, only created a minimal master page and added some snippet to it.

I do see a `404` in FireBug: `https://ourdomain.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/theme/Themed/E7642FC7/tokyo-B210DD14.themedcss?ctag=32`

I would like to restore Tokyo site layout back to its original form.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had the same issue with my SharePoint 2013 sub site.
So I had to set the theme again, that way it helped me.
I know it is weird issue but saved my day.
You should try that too.

The only thing problematic here is the theme CSS file. Don't know why that CSS file is not being found.

Hope this helps!